# SAS - Reverse Arthimetic Sign

Tags: sas

Is there any fucntion in SAS which converts positive to negative or negative to positive sign.

```
  DATA TEMP;     
   input X Y;    
 datalines;      
    2  100       
    3  -100       
    4  100  
   run;
```

When i add these values sum(y) the + has to be changed to - and '-' to '+' only when x is 3

```
proc sql;
    select X,sum(Y)                                                
    from TEMP                                 
    where X in (2,3) group by X;              
 quit;
```

is there any funciton?

When 3 = -100 then my Result should be 200
if 3 = 100 then my result should be 0

Comment: Can you give an example of the result?

Comment: So that should return 200?  ie, 100 + -(-100)?

Comment: Your SQL is wrong to generate that result; the group by and inclusion of x on the select statement would cause it to never add 100 to (100 or -100).

Comment: If you're doing this to gain meaningful results, I have a suspicion that perhaps your dataset isn't quite right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE WHEN` should be used in this case.  The negative sign itself handles the conversion.

```
DATA TEMP;
input X Y;
datalines;
2 100
3 -100
4 100
run;

proc sql; 
 select sum(case when x=3 then -Y else Y end)
   from TEMP
   where X in (2,3);
quit;
```